# Looking for a SVN solution for 3 users

Tags: svn

I'm looking for an simple SVN solution for my company.

Currently we're not using any version control. We would like to install a server app on one of the computers in the office and use it over the LAN for 3 users.

We develop websites using Visual Studio.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you are talking about a Windows-only setup. For that, I am very happy with [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) as a server (brain-dead easy to set up!) and [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org) as the client.

Comment: Seconded.  VisualSVN works like a champ in any small-to-medium environment in which I've worked.  And it's easy to back up the data.  The installation creates a place to store repositories (C:\SVNRepositories by default, I think) and you can just back up the files from there to whatever your backup solution is.  Restore is generally as easy as copying them back into place, all the history of the repositories is kept in those files.

Comment: VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN take all the guess work out of setting up and using an SVN directory. Definitely go with this.

Comment: @David it's better to do an SVNDump than to backup the Repositories directory directly.

Answer (score 2):

[AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is a great Visual Studio plugin which also happens to be free.

Comment: This of course is just the client, though it will work with any server

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed some good solutions -- sounds like VisualSVN may be best for your needs as a server, with AnkSVN or TortoiseSVN as clients (or both -- multiple clients can be used at the same time quite easily).

The only caveat to be aware of is that while SVN has great forward and backward compatibility, for the best experience ensure that the minor version numbers are the same, eg 1.6.x server with 1.6.y client.  It's a great productivity boost though over using no version control and very easy to get set up with.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sorry, but I couldn't understand what you mean but the minor versions..

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't that clear, plus the nomenclature is slightly ambiguous with SVN.  Basically as long as all your clients and server have the same minor version number (by which I mean all are 1.4 or 1.5 or 1.6) then everything will be fine.  Given the release cycles of Subversion though you could argue that these are actually major versions.  Concrete example:  server is 1.6.6, TortoiseSVN is 1.6.9 and AnkhSVN is 1.6.7 -- all 3 will work together quite happily.  It even means that the same developer can use TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN interchangeably in the same session.

Answer (score 0):

Use some hosted solutions. It costs very less and keeps you away from the maintenance hassle.
If you are not bothered about code ownership, you can go for free providers like google code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/free-online-private-svn-repositories

If you are bothered there are many commercial providers at a very cheap cost like svnrepository.com

So, all you will need is a client at your desktop. If you are using windows, you can use tortoisesvn, its free, stable and full of features.

Comment: Remote servers are a bad option for as due to bad response times to/from Israel as most of those services are in the states

Comment: yes, you are correct. I am from India, and my svn was hosted on svnrepository.com after using it for 3 years finally i decided to host it in a india based server. I bought a vps and installed trac and svn on fedora 12, everything works great now !! let me know if you need any help regarding the same.

Comment: As all of our current 3 users located in the same office, I think that for now the best solution would be just installing a server service on one of the development computers and allow the others to use it as a server over the LAN. From the answers on this page it seems lite setting up a SVN server is pretty easy.
Thank you for you updates and I'll be sure to contact you if we decide to use a remote solution like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [VsTortoise](http://vstortoise.codeplex.com/) for a nice plugin to visual studio.  It is built on top of TortoiseSVN.